# kernel compile error after update yocto morty to thud

Tags: linux-kernel, yocto, bitbake

I was using 'linux-toradex-4.1-2.0.x-imx' on yocto morty and every things was okay. but after updating all layer and poky to 'Thud' version, i get kernel do_compile error:

```
Sstate summary: Wanted 624 Found 66 Missed 558 Current 689 (10% match, 57% complete)
NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
WARNING: Variable key RDEPENDS_${KERNEL_PACKAGE_NAME}-base (${KERNEL_PACKAGE_NAME}-image) replaces original key RDEPENDS_kernel-base ( kernel-devicetree kernel-image).
ERROR: linux-toradex-samim-4.1-2.0.x-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed
ERROR: linux-toradex-samim-4.1-2.0.x-r0 do_compile: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /opt/yocto/toradex-morty/poky/build/tmp-glibc/work/colibri_imx6-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/linux-toradex-samim/4.1-2.0.x-r0/temp/log.do_compile.23716)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /opt/yocto/toradex-morty/poky/build/tmp-glibc/work/colibri_imx6-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/linux-toradex-samim/4.1-2.0.x-r0/temp/log.do_compile.23716
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
| NOTE: make -j 8 HOSTCC=gcc  -isystem/opt/yocto/toradex-morty/poky/build/tmp-glibc/work/colibri_imx6-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/linux-toradex-samim/4.1-2.0.x-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/include -O2 -pipe -L/opt/yocto/toradex-morty/poky/build/tmp-glibc/work/colibri_imx6-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/linux-toradex-samim/4.1-2.0.x-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib -L/opt/yocto/toradex-morty/poky/build/tmp-glibc/work/colibri_imx6-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/linux-toradex-samim/4.1-2.0.x-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/opt/yocto/toradex-morty/poky/build/tmp-glibc/work/colibri_imx6-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/linux-toradex-samim/4.1-2.0.x-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/opt/yocto/toradex-morty/poky/build/tmp-glibc/work/colibri_imx6-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/linux-toradex-samim/4.1-2.0.x-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/lib -Wl,-rpath,/opt/yocto/toradex-morty/poky/build/tmp-glibc/work/colibri_imx6-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/linux-toradex-samim/4.1-2.0.x-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib -Wl,-rpath,/opt/yocto/toradex-morty/poky/build/tmp-glibc/work/colibri_imx6-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/linux-toradex-samim/4.1-2.0.x-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/lib -Wl,-O1 HOSTCPP=gcc  -E uImage CC=arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -mno-thumb-interwork -marm -fuse-ld=bfd -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/yocto/toradex-morty/poky/build/tmp-glibc/work/colibri_imx6-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/linux-toradex-samim/4.1-2.0.x-r0=/usr/src/debug/linux-toradex-samim/4.1-2.0.x-r0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/yocto/toradex-morty/poky/build/tmp-glibc/work/colibri_imx6-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/linux-toradex-samim/4.1-2.0.x-r0/recipe-sysroot= -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/yocto/toradex-morty/poky/build/tmp-glibc/work/colibri_imx6-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/linux-toradex-samim/4.1-2.0.x-r0/recipe-sysroot-native=  -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/yocto/toradex-morty/poky/build/tmp-glibc/work-shared/colibri-imx6/kernel-source=/usr/src/kernel   LD=arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-ld.bfd   LOADADDR=0x10008000
|   GEN     ./Makefile
| scripts/kconfig/conf  --silentoldconfig Kconfig
|   CHK     include/config/kernel.release
|   UPD     include/config/kernel.release
|   GEN     ./Makefile
|   WRAP    arch/arm/include/generated/asm/bitsperlong.h
|   WRAP    arch/arm/include/generated/asm/cputime.h
|   WRAP    arch/arm/include/generated/asm/current.h

.
.
.
...after some warnings...
.
.
|                  from /opt/yocto/toradex-morty/poky/build/tmp-glibc/work-shared/colibri-imx6/kernel-source/include/linux/crypto.h:21,
|                  from /opt/yocto/toradex-morty/poky/build/tmp-glibc/work-shared/colibri-imx6/kernel-source/include/crypto/algapi.h:15,
|                  from /opt/yocto/toradex-morty/poky/build/tmp-glibc/work-shared/colibri-imx6/kernel-source/crypto/ghash-generic.c:15:
| /opt/yocto/toradex-morty/poky/build/tmp-glibc/work-shared/colibri-imx6/kernel-source/include/linux/log2.h:22:1: warning: ignoring attribute 'noreturn' because it conflicts with attribute 'const' [-Wattributes]
|  int ____ilog2_NaN(void);
|  ^~~
|   LD      crypto/crypto_blkcipher.o
|   LD      crypto/crypto_hash.o
|   LD      crypto/cryptomgr.o
|   LD      crypto/built-in.o
| Makefile:146: recipe for target 'sub-make' failed
| make[1]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
| Makefile:24: recipe for target '__sub-make' failed
| make: *** [__sub-make] Error 2
| ERROR: oe_runmake failed
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /opt/yocto/toradex-morty/poky/build/tmp-glibc/work/colibri_imx6-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/linux-toradex-samim/4.1-2.0.x-0/temp/log.do_compile.10534)
```

The kernel recipe is:

```
require recipes-kernel/linux/linux-imx.inc
include conf/tdx_version.conf

SUMMARY = "Linux kernel for Toradex Freescale i.MX based modules"

SRC_URI = "git://git@git.myco.int/kernel/linux-toradex-4.1-2.0.x-imx.git;protocol=ssh;branch=${SRCBRANCH} \
        file://defconfig \
        file://0002-Add-APP-K7-board-support.patch \
        "

# Load USB functions configurable through configfs (CONFIG_USB_CONFIGFS)
KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD += "${@bb.utils.contains('COMBINED_FEATURES', 'usbgadget', ' libcomposite', '',d)}"

LOCALVERSION = "-${TDX_VER_ITEM}"
# PV_append = "+git${SRCPV}"

SRCREV = "e420b7a49300560485af191ec63887d27da577db"
SRCBRANCH = "toradex_4.1-2.0.x-imx"

DEPENDS += "lzop-native bc-native"
COMPATIBLE_MACHINE = "(mx7|mx6)"

# defaults
TDX_VER_ITEM ??= "0"

inherit kernel
```

In 'meta-toradex-nxp' layer, i just saw 'linux-toradex_4.9-2.3.x.bb' and not 4.1-2.0.x, is it important? do i need to add somethings else to my recipe for being compile with 'Thud' too?

my bblayers.conf also is:

```
# LAYER_CONF_VERSION is increased each time build/conf/bblayers.conf
# changes incompatibly
LCONF_VERSION = "7"

BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}"
BBFILES ?= ""

BBLAYERS ?= " \
  ${TOPDIR}/../meta-myproj \
  \
  ${TOPDIR}/../meta-angstrom \
  \
  ${TOPDIR}/../meta-toradex-nxp \
  ${TOPDIR}/../meta-freescale \
  ${TOPDIR}/../meta-freescale-3rdparty \
  \
  ${TOPDIR}/../meta-toradex-bsp-common \
  \
  ${TOPDIR}/../meta-snappy \
  \
  ${TOPDIR}/../meta-linaro/meta-linaro-toolchain \
  ${TOPDIR}/../meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
  ${TOPDIR}/../meta-openembedded/meta-gnome \
  ${TOPDIR}/../meta-openembedded/meta-initramfs \
  ${TOPDIR}/../meta-openembedded/meta-networking \
  ${TOPDIR}/../meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia \
  ${TOPDIR}/../meta-openembedded/meta-python \
  ${TOPDIR}/../meta-openembedded/meta-webserver \
  \
  ${TOPDIR}/../meta-openembedded/meta-filesystems \
  \
  ${TOPDIR}/../meta-lxde \
  ${TOPDIR}/../meta-qt5 \
  ${TOPDIR}/../meta-qt5-extra \
  ${TOPDIR}/../meta-toradex-demos \
  ${TOPDIR}/../meta-freescale-distro \
  ${TOPDIR}/../meta-poky \
  ${TOPDIR}/../meta-browser \
  ${TOPDIR}/../meta-swupdate \
  \
  \
  ${TOPDIR}/../meta \
"
```

thank you so much in advance.

**Update**: thanks @Marcel, i checked [yocto manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#moving-to-the-yocto-project-2.6-release) and it say: "The GNU Compiler Collection version 8.2 is now used by default for compilation. If you still need to compile with version 7.x, GCC 7.3 is also provided. You can select this version by setting the and can be selected by setting the GCCVERSION variable to "7.%" in your configuration."

and then i insert 'GCCVERSION = "7.%"' to conf/local.conf too, but unfortunately it doesn't work still.

Comment: Have you cleaned your build environment properly before compiling the new version (thud)? OTOH, what do you mean by "is it important?"? You can upgrade your kernel as well, if you want to.

Comment: Don't you use this Toradex environment via [toradex-bsp-platform](http://git.toradex.com/cgit/toradex-bsp-platform.git/tree/default.xml?h=LinuxImage3.0)?

Comment: @danlor Yes, i 've used another build directory completely. just the download folder is shared for both 'Thud' and 'Morty. and about kernel, no, actually i don't want to upgrade kernel and i'm going to use my kernel in morty i.e 4.1-2.0.

Comment: @Nayfe no, i don't use it. do i need it too?

Comment: You don't need to use it but it helps to select versions of layers and recipes as they are tested by Toradex.

Comment: @Nayfe actually most of my layers are in the same revision, except 'meta-browser' and 'bitbake' that i'm in few upper revisions. and also i don't have 'meta-rust', 'meta-toradex-distro' and 'meta-toradex-tegra' layers.

Answer (score 3):

Please note that Thud is using a later gcc compiler (8.3 to be precise). Unfortunately, the obsolete Linux kernel 4.1 fails to compile with such gcc 8.3 and you would need to backport several patches to make that combination work. Plus note that OpenEmbedded is usually treating any warning as an error which you may also want to disable via compilation flags as otherwise, the number of patches required will be quite endless. Overall, the better approach may be to also properly adopt a later still supported Linux kernel like the toradex_4.14-2.0.x-imx we are now officially moving to in BSP 3.0b2.

Comment: thank you so much, you completely right. just as manual say '...GCC 7.3 is also provided', can i use gcc 7.3 for compiling kernel 4.1 too or not?